# SSH refuses to allow specific user to login directly via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, users

I have a specific user (Lets call them `user` through out this post) on a host that displays the following errors when trying to ssh via public key auth:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Direct login access is disallowed
```

I can mitigate the first error by using `ssh user@host "/bin/bash -i"`, but I am unable to get past the second error.

Things I have tried:

- I can `sudo -s` (or `sudo -i` to the user as root on the host directly.
- The user is locked down (`passwd -l user`), I unlocked and assigned a password to the user. Same problem. However I can `su - user` as any other user after the account is unlocked and a password is applied.
- I checked `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server, No entries for `AllowUsers`, `AllowGroups`, `DenyUsers`, `DenyGroups`.
- I am able to ssh directly as root no problem.
- I created a new user, and able to ssh directly to them as well.
- Confirmed ssh key selection and authorized_keys are set properly, however I dont think this is a key issue.
- `/etc/passwd` shows the user has `/bin/bash` set for their shell.
- `/etc/security/access.conf` is completely commented out with no settings set.
- restarted sshd many times.
- There is no `/etc/login.blocks` file.
- `/var/log/secure`, `/var/log/messages`, nor `journalctl -fu sshd` only show `Session open` then `Session closed for user user`
- `ssh user@host -vvvvvvv` just shows the `Direct login access is disallowed`
- rebooted the host.

Note: this is a rhel system that does not have its subscriptions enabled yet.

What gives? Why can I not access this

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
It was a script that someone wrote that was restricting access to the host.
The script was being run after anyone connected to the user via ssh.

This was implemented in `user`'s `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Here is the line that was showing in the file:

```
command="/home/user/script/that/was/causing/problems.sh", ssh-rsa ABC123hugepubliccipher==
```

After removing the `command=` section, users were then able to ssh in again.